# Insert row in a table from an other database with conditions

Tags: sql

I have 2 databases, with same structures but not same datas, 
I'm trying to insert datas from the source database to the target database, but only when the datas don't already exist in the target (if it exist I update it, it's already working).

This is what I've done now :

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM table@source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table@source ts
  WHERE ts.ID=table.ID AND ts.ID2=table.ID2
)
```

But it doesn't work...

Can someone help me please ?

exemple of what I want my request to do :

```
Target :
ID-ID2-NUM
01-001-100    ->    updated
02-002-200    ->    deleted
04-004-400    ->    deleted

Source :
ID-ID2-NUM
01-001-111    ->    used to update Target
02-001-020    ->    added in Target
03-003-300    ->    added in Target
```

The update and delete part already work fine.
All I'm having troubles with is the add line part.

Comment: Which DB are you using?  What do you mean by "Doesn't Work"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for, but I'm in my target DB, and I want to import lines from my source DB if they don't already exist in my target, based on ID and ID2 fields. Also, I'm working with Oracle. And by doesn't work, I mean my actual request doesn't add any lines. Also, I've added some details about what result I want to reach.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I've found my error :

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM table@source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table tt
  WHERE tt.ID=table.ID@source AND tt.ID2=table.ID2@source
)
```